# Getting updated DP of an user on Facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk

How can I get updated DP of an user in my Facebook app? Should I always load the DP on the fly or store it on my server? If I store it, then I don't think I'd able to update it as soon as user updates his/her DP.

Comment: Update using https://graph.facebook.com/USER_ID/picture.
Storing the DP is not good option.

Answer (score 0):

The better option would be to allow the user to give an option to refresh their contacts list.
OR
Perform an on-demand loading of the images.